# Saving an Excel worksheet as a Text file from IronPython

Tags: python, excel, vba, ironpython, excel-interop

I'm trying to use IronPython to export a series of Excel Worksheets to delimited text files using Interop.  I I think I should be using the `SaveAs` method, but I'm not clear what the equivalent python syntax is for it.  My current code keeps the worksheet in Excel format because the most obvious syntax would be `SaveAs(file ".txt", olTXT)`, but this fails.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceName('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel')
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel
xl = Excel.ApplicationClass()
xlFiles = open('\path\to\files.xls', 'r')
for file in xlFiles:
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file)
    ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.SaveAs(file ".txt")
```

How should I use it?  If you have a reference better than [Interacting with Excel](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Interacting_with_Excel), let me know.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ws.SaveAs(file ".txt", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText) was what I was looking for.  I found that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Python Tools for Visual has a new library for improved interaction with excel.  This was recently posted by Dino V  to the IronPython Users list.

> Dino Viehland dinov@.com via python.org to ironpython-use.,
>   python-announc.
>          We’re pleased to announce the release of Python Tools for Visual Studio 1.1 Alpha [http://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/69667].
>   Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) is an open-source plug-in for
>   Visual Studio which supports programming with the Python programming
>   language. This release includes new core IDE features, a couple of new
>   sample libraries for interacting with Kinect and Excel, and many bug
>   fixes for issues reported since the release of 1.0.